# Install node on Production server

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, server, production-environment

I want to install node on my server in production but the sudo command is not recognized by the server and I have not the permission to create folders and as I do not have the permissions I can not execute the chmod or chown command

Comment: What operating system is your server? Do you manage the server, or does someone else (i.e. shared hosting)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: how do we know the operating system of the server ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of Isaac's installation methods (a contributor of node.js) [found on his GitHub page](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814).

Try this:

```
echo prefix = ~/local >> ~/.npmrc
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: If OP doesn't have permission to create folders, how is that `mkdir` call going to work?

Comment: Is homebrew installed?

Comment: Ask OP. We don't even know if it's Windows, Linux, or OSX. Homebrew's not going to be much use on a Windows box, which I kinda suspect it is, given that Linux/OSX would usually have `sudo` available (even if OP's not allowed to use it).

Comment: Good point, updated with Isaac's "yet-another-option.sh" method.

Comment: Again, OP says they don't even have permissions to *create a folder*. I don't see how "run this shell script" (which will undoubtedly attempt to create folders, and won't work on Windows either) helps any more than the previous edit. We need more details to answer OP's question.

Comment: when I execute a command sudo apt-get install anything the server responds the sudo command is not recognized